# Trying to pull text from a certain span class

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I've been trying to print the text found in a `<span>` tag off of a website. Everything i've tried that doesn't give me a error has returned empty. printing absolutely nothing.

Heres My code:

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import ssl
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://www.hubzu.com/property/9007091467618-3632-Stokes-Drive-Sarasota-FL-34232'))
propertyname = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.h1')
propertyName1 = propertyname.text

print(propertyName1)
```

Heres the span class i'm trying to pull from:

```
<span class="h1">
<span id="streetName" class="header_bold propStreetAddress">
3632
Stokes Drive</span><span>, Sarasota, FL 34232</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much simpler to use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to scrape more complex HTML snippets:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.hubzu.com/property/9007091467618-3632-Stokes-Drive-Sarasota-FL-34232')
print(soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('span', {'class':'h1'}).text)
```

Output:

```
'\n\n3632\nStokes Drive, Sarasota, FL 34232\n'
```

Comment: It worked. Yeah, didn't even think about using `beautifulSoup` . Thanks!

Comment: @reggiejones Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that, there are two `span` tags with class `h1`. The first one is hidden. That is why you are getting the empty result because `find_element` returns the first element found by the locator.

Try the following:

```py
browser.get(('https://www.hubzu.com/property/9007091467618-3632-Stokes-Drive-Sarasota-FL-34232'))
propertyname = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.row.header-top-navigation span.h1')
print(propertyname.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not hold for all but in this case you can just use requests and bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.hubzu.com/property/9007091467618-3632-Stokes-Drive-Sarasota-FL-34232', headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.img-responsive')['alt'])
```